# Is the colorspace R package part of the Tidyverse? (conflicting information)

Tags: r, tidyverse, color-space

**Is the colorspace R package part of the Tidyverse?** Looking at [this list of Tidyverse included packages](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) it appears the answer is "No".

However, when I load the tidyverse via `library(tidyverse)` it appears that colorspace is loaded. I can request help with `?colorspace_function()` and the functions appear in my R Studio help window. If I start a new session of R, don't load any packages and run `?colorspace_function()` I get a *"no method"* error, as expected, indicating the package containing this function isn't loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to make sure we distinguish between "loaded" and "attached". Yes, `colorspace` is loaded, but it is not attached.

I can replicate what you describe, loading tidyverse and then successfully using `?choose_color`, but if I try to run `choose_color()` I get a function not found error.

Looking at `sessionInfo()`, `colorspace` is listed as "loaded via a namespace but not attached". So probably some package in tidyverse imports a package that imports a package that imports `colorspace`, and RStudio lets you follow the chain to get to a help page.

You can even play a game to try to get from [the tidyverse CRAN page](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyverse) to the colorspace CRAN page by clicking only on "imports" and "depends" links. I did it with tidyverse > ggplot2 > scales > munsell > colorspace. (Or you could write a script to trace the dependency tree.)

Answer (score 1):

Just because a package is loaded when you load tidyverse doesn't mean it is part of tidyverse. For example you can see that Rcpp, nlme, tools, lattice and grid are loaded. These are loaded because packages in the tidyverse depend on them for some aspect of their functionality. The "attached" packages shown here can be considered part of the tidyverse metapackage (among others).

```r
library("tidyverse"); sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3    
#> [5] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.0     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.1  
#> [9] tidyverse_1.3.0
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 xfun_0.11        haven_2.2.0      lattice_0.20-38 
#>  [5] colorspace_1.4-1 vctrs_0.2.0      generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.4.0 
#>  [9] yaml_2.2.0       rlang_0.4.2      pillar_1.4.2     withr_2.1.2     
#> [13] glue_1.3.1       DBI_1.0.0        dbplyr_1.4.2     modelr_0.1.5    
#> [17] readxl_1.3.1     lifecycle_0.1.0  munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0    
#> [21] cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.5      evaluate_0.14    knitr_1.26      
#> [25] fansi_0.4.0      highr_0.8        broom_0.5.2      Rcpp_1.0.3      
#> [29] backports_1.1.5  scales_1.1.0     jsonlite_1.6     fs_1.3.1        
#> [33] hms_0.5.2        digest_0.6.23    stringi_1.4.3    grid_3.6.1      
#> [37] cli_2.0.0        tools_3.6.1      magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.2  
#> [41] crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.3  zeallot_0.1.0    xml2_1.2.2      
#> [45] reprex_0.3.0     lubridate_1.7.4  assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_1.17  
#> [49] httr_1.4.1       R6_2.4.1         nlme_3.1-142     compiler_3.6.1
```